# how to get user input (args) and pass it to a collection taking method

Tags: java, collections, args

I've found an open source Java code that does IRR calculation. I would like to integrate this into my program. The idea is to input this java program some amounts and dates it then calculates IRR and returns a single number (double). The program excepts collection class as input (combination of numbers and dates) then returns the number. It can take as many number and dates as user wants. There are some sample code within the documentation, but all of them shows how this program gets parameters within the code hard coded. I'm trying to change it, so the program will get user input parse it into numbers and dates then ideally converts them into collection and pass it to the java program . I couldn't do it. I couldn't create collection object from user input and passed it to the program. I'm attaching sample code that does it values hardcodeded in the code, all I want to write a class that will dynamically capture user input (combination value and date, ideally one value, one date and so on) and pass it to the XIRR method.

```
public double xirr_issue5b() {
    double rate = new Xirr(
        new Transaction(-2610, "2001-06-22"),
        new Transaction(-2589, "2001-07-03"),
        new Transaction(-5110, "2001-07-05"),
        new Transaction(-2550, "2001-07-06"),
        new Transaction(-5086, "2001-07-09"),
        new Transaction(-2561, "2001-07-10"),
        new Transaction(-5040, "2001-07-12"),
        new Transaction(-2552, "2001-07-13"),
        new Transaction(-2530, "2001-07-16"),
        new Transaction(-9840, "2001-07-17"),
        new Transaction(38900, "2001-07-18")
    ).xirr();
    return rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is that the XIRR implementation in the open source package you refer to has `public Xirr(Transaction... tx){` which (if you are not familiar with var args) means you can have any number of elements of transactions. What it also allows is for you to enter in an array. XIRR also can take in Collections (such as ArrayLists) So what I do in the following code is:

- create a `Scanner` to read in the user input
- Create a date formatter to convert the strings to dates
- create an `ArrayList` that holds the transactions
- An iteration counter based on user input
- A `for` loop that loops the `iterations` amount predefined by the user and adds a new `Transaction` to the `ArrayList` each iteration taking in the user's next int and next String (converted to a date via date formatter).
- I feed the ArrayList into the Xirr method.

Try this:

```
//import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
//import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Date;
//import java.util.Scanner;

public double xirr_issue5b() {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Transaction> trans = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    int iterations = sc.nextInt();

    for(int k = 0; k < iterations; k++) {
        trans.add(new Transaction(sc.nextInt(), format.parse(sc.next())));
    }

    double rate = Xirr(trans).xirr();
    sc.close();

    return rate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good approach. I didn't understand  how you used sc.nextInt to limit the for loop. Doesn't it return next integer in the string?

Comment: Nope. nextInt is like, "Hey person. Did you enter in an int? Yes? Ok lets convert that String value of an int to an integer via Integer.parseInt(). No? It was not an int? Ok lets throw an inputmistmatcherror. In retrospect I should have accounted for if someone does not first enter in the number of value-dates that are to be entered. Like if I typed "hi" then it would say nope and exit the program. If I wanted 10 Transactions, then I would type 10, and then <value> <date> 10 times. Also can you mark my question as answered? I'm not sure if this comment here answered your question though.